# find and replace combination of string and number

Tags: sql, oracle, replace

we are getting as below in a table.

[image]

In the data in 3rd field (ie DETAILS field), if it has a combination of keyword : CIF ID ( it could be capitals, small, or combination of both) AND a number, they need to be replaced with MONS ID and data in MONS ID field respectively. please find expected output below.

[image]

Can someone please help me whether it is achievable ?

tried various sql functions, couldn't achieve result, do we need to go for other ? for ex bash scripting ?

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/REGEXP_REPLACE.html#GUID-EA80A33C-441A-4692-A959-273B5A224490

Comment: BTW, tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: Please don’t use images, use editable text so that it is copyable by someone who wants to try out a solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple string functions:

```sql
SELECT  mons_id,
        cif_id,
        CASE
        WHEN name_pos  > 0 AND value_pos > name_pos
        THEN SUBSTR(details, 1, name_pos - 1)
             || 'MONS ID'
             || SUBSTR(details, name_pos + 6, value_pos - name_pos - 6)
             || mons_id
             || SUBSTR(details, value_pos + LENGTH(cif_id))
        ELSE details
        END AS details
FROM    (
  SELECT t.*,
         INSTR(LOWER(details), 'cif id') AS name_pos,
         INSTR(details, cif_id) AS value_pos
  FROM   table_name t
);
```

or using regular expressions (which are less to type but slower):

```sql
SELECT  mons_id,
        cif_id,
        REGEXP_REPLACE(
          details,
          'cif id(.*?)' || cif_id,
          'MONS_ID\1' || mons_id,
          1,
          0,
          'i'
        ) AS details
FROM    table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (mons_id, cif_id, details) AS
SELECT 'ASD345', 1234567,   'CIF ID 1234567 xyz' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ASD569', 345245254, 'abc CIF ID: 345245254 xyz' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ASD508', 64647474,  'efg CIF ID mno 64647474 uvw' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ASD402', 12097655,  'hij klm' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

| MONS_ID | CIF_ID | DETAILS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ASD345 | 1234567 | MONS_ID ASD345 xyz |
| ASD569 | 345245254 | abc MONS_ID: ASD569 xyz |
| ASD508 | 64647474 | efg MONS_ID mno ASD508 uvw |
| ASD402 | 12097655 | hij klm |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2Z-W2zy6)

Comment: Can you please help to explain how "REGEXP_REPLACE" in the you provided working ?

Comment: @team9 `cif id` matches the string `cif id` then `(.*?)` matches zero-or-more of any character but as few as possible and stores the match in a capturing group and then it matches the `CIF_ID`'s value. Then it replaces it with the string `MONS_ID` then the first capturing group and then the `MONS_ID` value.